# Breakpoints in Laravel Blade templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any way that I can step through compilation of a Blade Template? Or even just dump the compiled Blade file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled blade file is cached in `app/storage/views`. Check it out there.

Comment: @JordanEllinger - View **assembly**? Do you mean the compile process? You can set breakpoints in [the compiler file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php), but I don't think that'll do you any good. It's a bunch of regexes running through the view. Like I said, you can set breakpoints in the cached view file.